# Changing value based on the option via ajax call

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I am trying to using ajax to update the `Price` when a user select the `size` it will fetch the price from the database using the pid.

Thanks

My size table looks like this

```
 pid    psize  pprice  ssize   sprice 
  1       12    25      12      30
  2       14    30      14      40
  3       16    35      16       45
  4       18    45
```

form

```
<form id="add" name="checkout" method="Post" action="checkout.php">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td width="160">Price:</td>
    <td>  </td> <!-- the price goes here and will change user 
       select from the option by default it should be what pid 1 psize is -->

</tr>
```

Below is how i have set the option for psize this

```
<tr>
  <td width="160">sizes*:</td>
  <td>
<select name="length"  id="length" class="small">
<?php
dbconnect();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT pid,psize FROM size");
$stmt->execute();
$i = 0;
foreach( $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row )
{
    if ($i == 0)
    {
        echo '<option',fillSelect('psize',$row['pid'],'',true),' value="'.$row['pid'].'">'.$row['psize'].'</option>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<option',fillSelect('psize',$row['pid']),' value="'.$row['pid'].'">'.$row['psize'].'</option>';
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
</select>

  </table> 
<input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="<?php echo $pid; ?>" />
<input type="Submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: Nice to know what you are trying to do.  What is your question?  What have you tried?

Comment: where is your jquery ajax code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/J4rXX/5/ I tried this javascript but i found out that someone could use javascript injection to change the value to whatever the what so my best option was to set everything up in a database and then use ajax to change the price when user select the option... It sound easy when i thought of it but hard to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `.change()`.

```
 $('#length').change(function(){
    $('#loader').show();
    // link to findprice.php
    var findprice = "link/to/your/findprice.php";
    $.post(findprice, {
    length: $('#length').val(),
    }, function(response){
    $('#price').html(response);
    });
    return false;
    });
```

And you add id to Price

```
<td id="price" width="160">Price:</td>
```